# In android This code is working Can anyone tell me why and how?

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

In Android I was practicing **recycling view** and I notice when i am **contverting an String type array into Integer type list** it is working fine as well as when i am putting **string type list into Interger type ArrayAdapter** it is working fine.

```
 String[] words = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"};

 List<Integer> listOfWords = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(words));

ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfWords);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You are using a raw type (for example `new ArrayList()` instead of `new ArrayList<String>`). Those effectively break the generic type system and shouldn't be used.

Comment: but there reference is not generic
List<Integer> listOfWords
@Joachim Sauer

Comment: Yes, and at that point the `<Integer>` is already a lie: it really contains strings, but due to raw types the compiler won't complain (except that you use a raw type: you **did** get a warning about that, didn't you? but you ignored it, cheekily).

Comment: Is it a good practice to use generic instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic instance"? If you mean `ArrayList<Foo>` instead of `ArrayList`: yes, absolutely. Using the raw type (i.e. the one without `<Foo>`) is only allowed for backwards compatibility with ancient code, actively breaks the type system and produces a warning whenever used (you did see the compiler warning, didn't you?). All of that is explained in the question/answer linked to above.

Comment: WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

Comment: WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.3.

Comment: WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually about Java rather than Android. Java Collections (e.g. ArrayList) use collections of objects under the hood and when you define an `ArrayList<Integer>` and an `ArrayList<String>` there actually no difference between them. They both hold a `Object[]` inside. So actually the only difference they have, is how the compiler treat them and if we use generic functions like `get` it will lead to a ClassCastException because you can find a unchecked cast inside their implementation.

ArrayAdapter is also defined in the same way and actually Lists and ArrayAdapter are not checking any types. In other words you've fooled the IDE, lint and compiler and because there is not type checking here, it can work without any problem (I'm not sure but I think inside ArrayAdapter there is a code which calls `toString` for each element or checks if it's a string or not using `instanceof`). In addition, even if you use `List<Object>` it is still able to function without any problem.